# How to add text to image when the image is hovered?

Tags: html, css, image, text

In my website, I have created a div tag, and I have set its background to a image, and whenever the image is hovered, the color darkens. Now I also want text to appear horizontally and vertically centered when the image is hovered. I tried to add text, but the text does not even appear on the image.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div id="countries-hitched-div">
    <h1> Places Hitched </h1>    
    <div id="first" class="image">
        <h1 id="first-text"> India </h1>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
#first {
    background: url('Images/Home Page/first-quote-image-final.jpg');
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position:relative;
}

.image:hover > .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
}

#first-text {
    position: absolute;
    color: black   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the changes in `#first-text`:

```
.image:hover #first-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You will get the absolute element centered(Vertical and horizontal) inside relative element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add this correction in your code, this `aligns` your overlay `text` in center,

```
#first-text {
 text-align:center;
 position: absolute;
 color: black;
 width:100%;
 top:45%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Welcome :-) @PiyushMaheshwari Do accept or up-vote if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First off: Don't set too many new Properties on `:hover`. If possible, set all properties on page load and only change the necessary properties when `:hover`'ed or `:focus`'ed.

Next, you got multiple options to center the h1:

- Set a `line-height` for the h1 and `text-align: center` ([like this example](http://codepen.io/TheLexoPlexx/pen/ZLNReX?editors=1100#))
- Center the h1 with a table ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers))
- Use flexbox ([like in this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

Comment: How to set properties to page load and what is :focus, as I am not a professional in web development? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Look at this example: http://i.imgur.com/hrucKnj.png
The properties of "some-property" are set on page load.
`:hover` is a pseudo-class which is activated on (in this case) hovering that element. All properties set in there are changed based on the class that the `:hover` is used on.
`:focus` is just another pseudo-class just like `:hover` but with a different use. When clicking in a text field for example, the `:focus` is activated.

Answer (score 0):

For center try text-align center and for hover effects try changing the opacity.
Something like:

```css
#first {
    background: url('Images/Home Page/first-quote-image-final.jpg');
    position: relative;
}
.image {    
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position:relative;
}
.image:hover > .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: .5;
}
#first-text {
    position: absolute;
    color: black
}
 #first-text {
       text-align:center;
       position: absolute;
       color: black;
       width:100%;
       top:45%;
       opacity:0.0
 }
#first:hover #first-text{
    opacity:1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="countries-hitched-div">
        <h1> Places Hitched </h1>   
            <div id="first" class="image">
                <h1 id="first-text"> India </h1>
                <div class="overlay"></div>



            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the image to be visible even if it is not hovered, the thing I want is that the image should darken when it is hovered. Thanks for the answer